# Why does Spring's HandlerInterceptorAdapter is called twice only when my controller has @RequestMapping (produces = ...)?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

After a long time debugging my app, I realized something which makes no sense to me. Whenever I call a controller annotated as exemplified below, my Interceptor is executed twice.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getMedia(String url) throws IOException {
...
}
```

For testing purposes I removed the "produces" part and the same interceptor is only called once.

Can someone please enlighten me why is this happening? The fact it is being called twice is generating errors, because on the second call all request headers are empty and thus my validations fail.

My interceptor is simply an implementation as follow:

```
public class AuthenticatorInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
        //validations
        return super.preHandle(request, response, handler);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if your class also has a @RequestMapping annotation producing a different mimetype. Maybe this is the source of your problem, since both "produces" declaration might be the reason your interceptor is being called twice.

Comment: You are right, I had both annotation using "produces" and removing the class level one made the interceptor to be called only once.